# get list of NoneType values 'None'

Tags: python, lambda, plotly, nonetype

I am new to Python. I'm trying to get a list of NoneType values to create a subplot (plotly library). The following setup is required to create subplots with different specs:

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3, specs=[ [{'colspan':3}, None, None],
                                                      map(lambda x: {}, ew) ],
                          shared_xaxes=False,   shared_yaxes=False,
                          start_cell='top-left', print_grid=False)
```

So, based on the values in the list "ew", a list of Nonetype values is needed. The values in the list can vary and so should the list of Nonetypes.

1. Solution: List of Strings, List comprehension:

   `lst =', '.join([str(None) for ticker in ew])`

   Problem: Strings - convert to Nonetype possible?
2. Solution: Lambda function that inserts None for each value in ew.

   `map(lambda x: None, ew)`

   Problem: Brackets of the list. Can't get rid of them.

The Solution I am looking for:

```
print(lst)
None, None
<type 'NoneType'>
```

so that:

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3, specs=[ [{'colspan':3}, lst],
                                                      map(lambda x: {}, ew) ],
                          shared_xaxes=False,   shared_yaxes=False,
                          start_cell='top-left', print_grid=False)
```

Is there a way to get such a list? or a better solution over a embedded function?

**EDIT**
since there is still an error by inserting the following 'lst' to fig:

```
lst = print(*map(lambda x: None, ew), sep= ', ') #returns None, None 

print('{lst}'.format(**locals())) #returns only None
```

-> is this a possible explanation?

Comment: Doesn't `[None] * len(ew)` work?

Comment: unfortunately not. gets [None, None] - Brackets seem to be the problem, [None], [None] doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.x you can try this to print a list without the brackets even if there's a NoneType data included:

```
print (*lst, sep=', ') #lst = [None, None]
```

It should output:

```
None, None
```

If you're using Python 2.x you can also do this by using `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: This seems correct. However, it doesn't work in the combination.    

    print(* [None]), print(*[None]) 
works, but    
print(*[None,None], sep =',') 
doesn't work. Is this an error of the plotly function or is there a difference in the "comma" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a list and then remove the brackets later.

```
a = [None, None, None, None, None]  # an example of a list you might want
```

and you can print it without the brackets like :

```
print str(a)[1:-1]
```

Comment: NoneType is needed. This string is therefore not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for my question: 
Make one whole list with the dictionary at the first place.

```
tr = []
for ticker in ew:
    if ew.index(ticker) ==0:
        tr.append({'colspan': len(ew)})
    else:
        tr.append(None)
```

into fig:

```
fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=3, specs=[ tr, map(lambda x: {},ew)],
                          shared_xaxes=False, shared_yaxes=False,
                          start_cell='top-left', print_grid=False)
```

more pythonic solutions are welcome.